# Change the pricing tier of an Azure Front Door from Classic to Standard

Tags: azure-front-door

Is it possible to change the pricing tier of an Azure Front Door from Classic to Standard?

How to do this? I couldn't find in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In order to switch between tiers, you will need to recreate the Azure Front Door profile.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/standard-premium/tier-comparison

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).